# Computing arrival rate

Tags: probability, poisson-process

A store opens at 8 A.M. From 8 until 10 customers arrive at a Poisson rate of four an hour. Between
10 and 12 they arrive at a Poisson rate of eight an hour. From 12 to 2 the arrival rate increases
steadily from eight per hour at 12 to ten per hour at 2; and from 2 to 5 the arrival rate drops
steadily from ten per hour at 2 to four per hour at 5. Determine the probability distribution of the
number of customers that enter the store on a given day.

First, i have to find $\lambda (t)$. This is what i did:

For a day, the arrival rate can be written 
$\lambda (t) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0{\text{ if }}0 \leqslant t < 8 \hfill \\
  4{\text{ if 8}} \leqslant t < 10 \hfill \\
  8{\text{ if }}10 \leqslant t < 12 \hfill \\
  0{\text{ if }}17 \leqslant t < 24 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

how can i find $\lambda (t)$ for $12 \leqslant t < 14$ and $\lambda (t)$ for $14 \leqslant t < 17$ ? I'am stuck here.

Comment: Make a linear approximation between the times. So between 12 and 2, $\lambda (t) = 8 + (t-12)$. If I understand correctly, you can integrate over $t$ to get the lambda over the day.

Comment: I dont understand. What formula did you used?

Comment: I used the line-between-two-points formula. $(12,8),(14,10)$ are the points to join.

Comment: Were you able to work it out?

Comment: Why you choose $(12,8)$ and not $(8,12)$ ?

Comment: I placed $t$ on the $x$ axis and lamba on the $y$ axis.

Comment: @Cehhΐro So, if between 12 and 2 we have $\lambda(t) = 8 + (t-12)$, What about from 2 to 5? From textbook, this is found to be $-2t + 38$. But I really don't know how that was arrived at. Also, what is the rationale behind using the linear approximations between the times instead of listing the time as in from 8-10am and 10-12pm?